# How to integrate Sphinx-generated Latex code in existing Latex documents?

Tags: latex, documentation-generation, python-sphinx

I've used Sphinx to document a Python library. So far this works great, I get nice HTML and LaTeX output. Concerning Latex, Sphinx generates a complete standalone document with lots of special packages and configurations.

But, I would like to integrate the generated Latex files within an already existing Latex project (more precise: in the appendix of a book). In particular I want the Sphinx-generated documentation pages to have the header, footer and section heading styles of the *parent* document. I guess I could somehow transfer the relevant parts by manually removing unneeded stuff and adjusting various options in the *tex* files generated by Sphinx. However, probably this is going to be a very tedious fiddling taking too much of my time (thinking of conflicting packages and options I have to detect and fix).

Does Sphinx' Latex-Builder support such a use case? If not, is there a more general approach how to *merge* independent Latex-documents?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: If you want to include one document in another, it's possible you could do that by creating a group, gobbling all input until the next `\begin{document}`, then processing input as normal.  But this won't fix package conflicts.  Why not the `pdfpages` package?

Comment: Thanks for the hint to `pdfpages`. Until now it looks like the only practical option. Though, the included pages do not integrate well with regard to headers, footers and counters. I tried a manual integration on the *tex* file level, but after adding the `sphinx` package to the including parent document, its layout was an absolute mess - these are the kind of conflicts I would like to avoid. Maybe I need a special Sphinx builder, which creates *tex* files one can include in other documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no generally valid answer to this question. I've asked this question on the *sphinx* mailing list and received an [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/48c84a8a4f26145a/38347979ca14c125) which basically says one has to manually extract and partly convert the relevant parts of the latex code generated by sphinx - a less expensive solution does not yet exist.