# integrate Sphinx-generated Latex code in existing Latex documents

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, python-sphinx

How to integrate sphinx-generated latex code in existing latex documents?
My question is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336335/how-to-integrate-sphinx-generated-latex-code-in-existing-latex-documents), but i thought after in 6 years a method to solve this should have been found. If not is there now some steps to follow to manually do it? best practices?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your LaTeX repertory the same files Sphinx puts in a LaTeX build repertory, i.e. currently at least

- sphinx.sty
- footnotehyper-sphinx.sty
- sphinxhighlight.sty
- sphinxmulticell.sty

and you must add `\usepackage{sphinx}` to your LaTeX document preamble.

You may also need some of the special definitions Sphinx adds to preamble of a LaTeX document.